# iOS Unity Firebase Messenger Xcode Compile Error: FIRDynamicLinks

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

Building with Unity 2018.4.2 - Xcode 10.2 - Latest iOS Targets
Firebase Latest (6.1.1) for Unity with .Net 4

For Firebase We are using the following unity packages:
 - FirebaseMessaging.unitypackage
 - FirebaseAnalytics.unitypackage

Get the following Build Error in Xcode:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDynamicLinks", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppApp.a(invites_receiver_internal_ios_aa7b75b2efc3269e88f1077e55250e5a.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

On another Machine same error however armv7 target:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDynamicLinks", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppApp.a(invites_receiver_internal_ios_aa7b75b2efc3269e88f1077e55250e5a.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Tested Solutions (no solution yet):

- Obj-C to frameworks (was already there)
- Updated Cocoa Pods to Latest
- Deleted Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Updated Cocoa Pods and deleted caches

The strangest thing is this only started happening on Monday, previously was working, nothing else was changed, so this leads to believe this is Google changed something in their Cocoa pods library which is linking agains't another package which is not included now.

*Problem does not occur in the same Android Variant of the Project.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

It now requires you to also include and install Firebase: DynamicLinks in order to compile for iOS.

- FirebaseDynamicLinks.unitypackage

[image: FirebaseDynamicLinks.unitypackage image]

So install the following package into your unity project from the download of Firebase Unity.

Comment: Thank you for this solution!